# When I use flutter run in powershell it does not run the application in an emulator it asks to choose EDGE. windows.Can anyone please help me with it?

Tags: powershell, flutter, android-studio

Basically I just want the application to run on an emulator when I use the flutter run command .I want to running without using the android studio .It will be of great help if I get this answered . Thank you in advance [image].I have attached a screenshot of it

Could you please tell me how to connect an emulator with flutter.Emulator runs fine in Android Studio but I want to run it with flutter within the command promt.Thanks a lot for answering that really helps!!
PS C:\Users\sharu> flutter devices
3 connected devices:

Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1052]
Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.77
Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.48
PS C:\Users\sharu>  How do I  get a emulator here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that links to images posted on external sites may break over time, so the preference is to directly embed images, which is supported by Stack Overflow. Also, for text output, it's best to simply paste the text into the question instead of posting a screenshot of it. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with the [`flutter` CLI](https://flutter.dev/docs/reference/flutter-cli) - do tell me if I'm wrong.

It seems that `flutter run` can target multiple registered devices.

Therefore, with multiple devices registered, you are *prompted* to pick the target device, which is what you're seeing.

You have two options for avoiding this prompt:

- Use `flutter run -d <deviceId>` to target a *specific* device, where `<deviceId>` represents one of the identifiers listed in parentheses in the numbered choices in your screenshot; e.g., `edge`.
- Use `flutter run -d all` to target *all* devices.

Comment: @SharuLakshmiBalakrishnan: Again, I'm not familiar with `flutter`, so the CLI documentation linked to from the answer is all that I can offer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But could you please tell me how to connect an emulator with flutter.Emulator runs fine in Android Studio but I want to run it with flutter within the command promt.Thanks a lot for answering that really helps!!
PS C:\Users\sharu> flutter devices
3 connected devices:

Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1052]
Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.77
Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.48
PS C:\Users\sharu>  How do I  get a emulator here